# i get error that database locked;

Tags: c#, sqlite

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteException' occurred in System.Data.SQLite.dll
>
> Additional information: database is locked

My code:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    con.Open();
    string name = textBox1.Text;
    kom = con.CreateCommand();

    kom.CommandText = "insert into test(name) values('" + name + "')";
    kom.ExecuteNonQuery();

    textBox1.Clear();
    con.Close();
}
```

Comment: I doubt .net has anything to do with this lock. Have you added Pooling=true in your connection string as well are you able to browse sql lite server from your machine?

Comment: I didn't added. i have just added and it worked. thanks for your answer and help

Comment: [SQL Injection alert](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms161953%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) - you should **not** concatenate together your SQL statements - use **parametrized queries** instead to avoid SQL injection - check out [Little Bobby Tables](https://xkcd.com/327/)

Answer (score 0):

***Set connection string with Pooling=true.***

*Why? Database gets locked for several reasons.*

Connection pooling reduces the number of times that new connections must be opened. The pooler maintains ownership of the physical connection. It manages connections by keeping alive a set of active connections for each given connection configuration.
Refer msdn for more https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/sql-server-connection-pooling